# When to prefer LinkedBlockingQueue over ArrayBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blockingqueue

When to prefer `LinkedBlockingQueue` over `ArrayBlockingQueue`?

Which data structure to use among `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ArrayBlockingQueue` when:

1. You want an efficient read and write
2. should have lesser memory footprints

Although there is a similar question but it does not highlight the fact that which should be preferred?

Links:

- [Java: ArrayBlockingQueue vs. LinkedBlockingQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061882/java-arrayblockingqueue-vs-linkedblockingqueue)
- [What is the Difference between ArrayBlockingQueue and LinkedBlockingQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375334/what-is-the-difference-between-arrayblockingqueue-and-linkedblockingqueue?rq=1)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Boris the Spider has already outlined the most visible difference between `ArrayBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingQueue` - the former is always bounded, while the latter can be unbounded.

So in case you need an unbounded blocking queue, `LinkedBlockingQueue` or a `LinkedTransferQueue` used as a `BlockingQueue` are your best bets from the `java.util.concurrent` toolbox.

But let's say you need a bounded blocking queue.
In the end, you should choose an implementation based on extensive experimenting with a simulation of your real-world workload.
Nevertheless, here are some notes that can help you with your choice or with interpreting the results from the experiment:

- `ArrayBlockingQueue` can be created with a configurable (on/off) scheduling fairness policy. This is great if you need fairness or want to avoid producer/consumer starvation, but it will cost you in throughput.
- `ArrayBlockingQueue` pre-allocates its backing array, so it doesn't allocate nodes during its usage, but it immediately takes what can be a considerable chunk of memory, which can be a problem if your memory is fragmented.
- `ArrayBlockingQueue` should have less variability in performance, because it has less moving parts overall, it uses a simpler and less-sophisticated single-lock algorithm, it does not create nodes during usage, and its cache behavior should be fairly consistent.
- `LinkedBlockingQueue` should have better throughput, because it uses separate locks for the head and the tail.
- `LinkedBlockingQueue` does not pre-allocate nodes, which means that its memory footprint will roughly match its size, but it also means that it will incur some work for allocation and freeing of nodes.
- `LinkedBlockingQueue` will probably have worse cache behavior, which may affect its own performance, but also the performance of other components due to false sharing.

Depending on your use-case and how much do you care about performance, you may also want to look outside of `java.util.concurrent` and consider [Disruptor](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) (an exceptionally fast, but somewhat specialized bounded non-blocking ring buffer) or [JCTools](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools) (a variety of bounded or unbounded queues with different guarantees depending on the number of producers and consumers).

Comment: Nice answer! I agree with what you have mentioned also I would like to emphasis (again) the fact that ArrayBlockingQueue is backed by an array that size will never change after creation. Setting the capacity to Integer.MAX_VALUE would create a big array with high costs in space. ArrayBlockingQueue is always bounded.

LinkedBlockingQueue creates nodes dynamically until the capacity is reached. This is by default Integer.MAX_VALUE. Using such a big capacity has no extra costs in space. LinkedBlockingQueue is optionally bounded.

Comment: Since most of java GCs are compacting, problems with heap fragmentation don't really exist.

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov what are the `JCTools` alternatives for `BlockingQueue`?

Comment: Does `ArrayBlockingQueue` move all of the elements in the backing array up by one index every time you remove the head element from the queue?  If so, it seems like a simple operation like popping the head element off the queue could be extremely expensive.

Answer (score 21):

From the [JavaDoc for `ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)

> A **bounded** blocking queue backed by an array.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

From the [JavaDoc for `LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html):

> An **optionally-bounded** blocking queue based on linked nodes.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

So if you need a **bounded** queue you can use either, if you need an **unbounded** queue you must use `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

For a **bounded** queue, then you would need to benchmark to work out which is better.

Comment: To be able to declare an unbounded queue is also one of the reasons as specified in my answer as linkedList is unbounded whereas arrays are not.

Comment: @rahulroc you actually never say that at all, and never provide any evidence for your assertions. Saying that an array backed collection is bounded is also simplistic and untrue - an `ArrayList` is array backed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BoristheSpider. Your are right this is one good reason for preference, but do we have differences in performance when : 
1. You want an efficient read and write 
2. there is no concern on whether queue be bounded or not 
3. should have lesser memory footprints  ?

Comment: @VaibhavGupta what do you mean by `2`? How can you have _no concern_? If you create an `ArrayBlockingQueue` then you **must** specify the size of the underlying array. If you set it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` your computer will likely crash, so you have to pick a realistic number. If there is no realistic number, then you require an **unbounded** queue.