# Concurrent Queue Data Structure with ArrayList as Element

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

#### Problems in Details

Will it cause any issue when using data structure e.g `ArrayBlockingQueue<ArrayList<MyClass>>`
with multiple threads?

#### Background

In a high level, i am trying to achieve that I have one producer which will produce a giant list. In order to speed up the processing. I decide to use multiple consumers(threads) consuming the giant list produced by the producer.

#### My Proposal Solution

I will be converting the giant list to multiple relatively smaller list and in order to ensure its thread safe, I will enqueue these smaller lists to a concurrent data structure. So in multi-threads scenario, each thread just poll the concurrent queue to get one list and work on it.

#### Problem Statement

In multi-threads scenario, I understand we have to use the concurrent data structure to avoid thread interference and build happen-before relation.

- But will it be safe that using non-thread-safe data structure as element of thread-safe data structure？
- Will it cause any issue when using data structure e.g `ArrayBlockingQueue<ArrayList<MyClass>>`
  with multiple threads?
- Will it be any impact to the performance?

Comment: any help/suggestion are welcomed!

Comment: Have you considered enqueuing the individual `MyClass` elements one by one? Maybe your producer does not need to build up the huge list in the first place that way?

Comment: @Thilo .thanks for coming up with this solution.  

To my use case, i will only have limited number of threads as consumer. so even with enqueuing the individual   ` MyClass ` , will it bring down the performance? Concurrent data structure internally is using reentrant lock, it may be possible that one thread is blocking another thread for a brief time.

So if i use ` ConcurrentQueue<List<MyClass>>`, then i can reduce the interaction   of between different threads and the shared variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be an obvious problem with this approach.

> will it be safe that using non-thread-safe data structure as element of thread-safe data structure？

This is safe as long as you properly coordinate (or avoid) concurrent access to the non-thread-safe inner data structure. The `ArrayBlockingQueue` ensures the happens-before relation is established when you access its elements via on of the `peek`, `poll` or related methods.

> Will it cause any issue when using data structure e.g `ArrayBlockingQueue<ArrayList<MyClass>>` with multiple threads?

No, this is what [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is intended for as long as you coordinate access to the inner lists (see above).

> Will it be any impact to the performance?

In general the approach where the single producer partitions the list into sub-lists might not be optimal. The producer does not / should not know about the number of consumers and their bandwidth and thus in general does not know what partition sizes work well. A better approach might be to use an `ArrayBlockingQueue<MyClass>` and from the consumer side always consume multiple elements in one go by calling [`drainTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection,int)) for a suitable number `maxElements` of elements.

Comment: Thx for ur comments.  
  
so the short answer is that 1. It will not be any issue if I use drainTo to a new list and start working on it. 2. Performance will not be affected at all, since each thread has their own list as they are working on a single thread process.   

do i understand it correctly?

Comment: Thanks. I will update my question once I completed this project. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Thanks the Answer from michid@ and Thilo@

#### Final Resolution

I end up using `LinkedBlockingQueue<List<MyObjClass>>` and have multiple child threads polling from the queue. Each child thread will take list of `MyObjClass` to work on.

This resolution does not have any impact to slow down the performance.
For why i am choosing `LinkedBlockingQueue` over `ArrayBlockingQueue` see [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967792/when-to-prefer-linkedblockingqueue-over-arrayblockingqueue)